# How to post data from jquery to webapi (mvc4.0)?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to call below request from cross domain on local machine. It calls but at serverside it could not found passed values in function parameters. I am using MVC4 WebAPI.

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/webapp1/api/TicketAPI/GetTicketsByFilter',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: { 
        Condition: '2', 
        StartDate: 's', 
        EndDate: 's',    
        Priority: '2', 
        Status: '2', 
        Category: 's',
        PageNumber:1,
        PageSize: 10,
        OrderBy: 's', 
        OrderDir: 'asc' 
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        debugger;
        alert(data);
        // result = JSON.parse(data.lstRecords);
        // $(result).each(function (e) {
        //     var p = new Date(this["CreatedOnUtc"]);
        //     $("#list").addRowData(e, this);
        // });  
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('fine');
    }
});
}
```

```
//below is the serverside code .

using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
//using System.Web.Mvc;
using CS.Services.Tickets;
using CS.Core;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using CS.Services;
using System.Web.Http;
using CS.Web.Utility;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Configuration;

public TicketSearchResult GetTicketsByFilter(SearchParameter ObjParameter)
{
    //I always found ObjParameter is null .It should have some values
    //some code here/
}
```

How to post values in ObjParameter so that it has values instead of null.?

```
 public class SearchParameter
    {
       public SearchParameter()
       {
        PageNumber = 1;
        PageSize = 100;
        OrderBy = "TicketID";
        OrderDir = "ASC";
    }

    public string Condition { get; set; }
    public string StartDate { get; set; }
    public string EndDate { get; set; }
    public string Priority { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public string OrderBy { get; set; }
    public string OrderDir { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The use of `JSONP` and `crossdomain: true` is a little odd for a local domain request. Can you provide the code to the `SearchParameter` class, so we can see the properties you're trying to bind to.

Comment: The object sent from client to server is bound to action parameter by the framework. Based on the property name, it will convert the value. You are initializing data that's not compatible hence it will fail. e.g. startDate = 's'???

Comment: added the SearchParameter in question.

Comment: You can't use jsonp on a post request. It's for GET only.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if your json object has all the fields (and the same type) as SearchParameter class.

Then, you can make a call like this:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/webapp1/api/TicketAPI/GetTicketsByFilter',
        type: 'POST',
        data:JSON.stringify({ Condition: '2', StartDate: 's', EndDate:'s',Priority: '2', Status: '2', Category: 's',PageNumber:1,PageSize:10,OrderBy:'s',OrderDir:'asc' }),            
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            //your code
        },
        error: function (x, y, z) {
            alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
        }
    });
```

Comment: How is this *any* different to what the OP is already doing? His issue is that the data being sent in the request is not bound to his Model, not that the request is failing.

Comment: When the request is not bound to the Model usually indicates that the serialized value is not maching with the deserialized target type. Additionally, I am recommending change the way to post the data, so the deserialization to the SearchParameter can be done.

Comment: @skiskd : You are missing the blank constructor too for the SearchParameter class. You'll need a blank constructor.